# Is there a difference between 'pluvia' and 'imber'?

Tags: word-comparison

It occurred to me yesterday that I know two Latin words for rain:
[*pluvia*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=pluvia&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)
and
[*imber*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=imber&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
However, I don't seem to know how these two words compare to each other, and the L&S entries offer little help.
Are they essentially synonymous, or are there differences I should be aware of?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is a technical difference, though the meanings tend to shade one into the other.

Roughly, *pluvia* is the wet stuff itself, the falling water that comprises the shower, *imber*.

More or less as you would in English, it's quite legitimate to use either, as you wish, to describe the actual weather. *Imber*, however, does tend to mean heavy or cold rain, rather than a gentle, soft shower. An example that comes to mind is the description of the weather on the day of Galba's downfall (Tac. Hist. 1, 18):

*Quartum idus Ianuarias, foedum imbribus diem, tonitrua et fulgura et caelestes minae ultra solitum turbaverunt.*

But if you were translating Portia's plea from the Merchant of Venice, where 'the quality of mercy . . . . . droppeth like the gentle rain from heaven', *pluvia* — the rain water itself — would be the word to use.